# Problem Installing elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, grub

Well i was using Mint on dual boot with Witndos 10, so i wanted to remove Mint and install eOS with Windows.
I've been trying to install for a long time using a DVD, but every time that i finish instalation a error message appears:

```
Unable to install grub in /dev/sda.
This is a fatal error.
```

Then i reboot my laptop and a grub rescue screen shows up.
I tryed a lot of options but none of them worked.
When the system is being loading a message shows and dissapear:

> Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
>   MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list

I don't know what to do. I've already done [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886367/grub-install-dev-sda-failed-for-dual-boot-with-windows-10) tutorial, but when get the line:

```
grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --force
```

The terminal says:

```
grub install error doesn't look like a efi partition
```

At the moment i already gave up of trying.

My laptop is a Lenovo G400s, BIOS doesn't have secure boot just UEFI, but now i am using Legacy mode. This [link](https://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2017/04/como-acessar-bios-de-um-notebook-da-lenovo.html) shows how my setup Bios is like.

Comment: I have seen this "error" before ... when the disk is created as a gpt rather than MS-DOS partition table ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying one more time, at beginning of installations , on menu to select which options of boot, there was three options to select, i just tried other option.